# MIPI DSI touch screen compatibility with Orange Pi 5B

Tags: display, hdmi, touchscreen, mipi

**TD;DR**
Is DSI and MIPI D-PHY TX 4 lane the same thing?

---

I came across a "Waveshare 7.9 **touch** display for Raspberry Pi" which has two options, [HDMI](https://www.waveshare.com/product/7.9inch-hdmi-lcd.htm) and [DSI](https://www.waveshare.com/7.9inch-dsi-lcd.htm).

As I can see from [Orange Pi's website](https://www.orangepi.org/html/hardWare/computerAndMicrocontrollers/details/Orange-Pi-5B.html), apart from having HDMI port, it states it has **MIPI D-PHY TX 4Lane**

I googled but it got me more confused; MIPI DSI is one thing. Does it mean I should go with the DSI variant of the screen and expect things to work?
Is there any advantage of HDMI over DSI in terms of processing power/speed that I should be aware of?

Please excuse my inexperience in this field.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make things short, you can use

- "MIPI D-PHY" with "DSI (Display Serial Interface)" display with the same number of lanes, and similarly
- "MIPI C-PHY" with "CSI (Camera Serial Interface)"
- If it isn't mentioned C-PHY, D-PHY, DSI, or CSI, you can still use it just make sure the no. of lanes are same.

I believe this is the convention. A 4-lane mipi display port can be used for a 4-lane mipi display.

---

Apart from this, you should definitely read [this](https://www.arasan.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/All-about-MIPI-C-PHY-and-D-PHY.pdf), atleast the first page.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned, if you get a 4-lane MIPI-DSI display, it will technically be compatible. The orange pi "official 10.1" LCD DSI interface driver is enabled with an "overlay" via the orangepi-config utility which comes with official orange pi distros. See the O'pi manual for instructions on how to run orangepi-config and check lcd1 and/or lcd2 depending on which connector on the Pi is used.
However, I've got a WKS WKS70WSV084-WCT 1024x600 MIPI-DSI panel and getting Linux configured to use something with different resolution or timing from the Orange Pi official 10.1 display has been a challenge. It requires recompiling the Linux kernel with a driver for that display. I would recommend getting an HDMI display unless you are making a product based on the Pi and need to save on cost by eliminating the HDMI hardware.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the input. I keep bumping only into 40 pin mipi displays but the OPi has 30 pin connector. Any suggestions will be appreciated :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm likely very underqualified for this myself, and I've been searching desperately for an answer to this question, and all I ever come up with is that Orange Pi 5 uses 4 lanes, and Rasp pi uses 2 lanes, but then I also see there might be some pin differences, like the actual number of pins on the cable MAY? be different with literally no definitive answer to that. And the only compatible screens that are made by the same company are the only thing I consider that they have dramatically overpriced.

Comment: Hi! As far as I went down this rabbit hole, I believe a 4 lane mipi display can be used with Orange Pi 5/5B and similarly, you need a 2 lane display for raspberry as you already mentioned :)